# Looking for specific files that contain footer/header information IIS/Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: html, css, web, footer

I was trying to work on this webpage that includes a header, iframe and a footer.
My objective is to change the position of the footer, and normally I would tweak the HTML/CSS to get it done, however I am unable to find a file that contains the code for the position so that I could work on it.

I am working on Microsoft SQL Server and do not understand the File Directory system. Could anyone point me to where there might be relevant files related to the page layout or position in IIS/Microsoft SQL Server.

Upon inspection I see directories named 'Modules, Logs, Bin, Admin, Default.aspx, error.htm' and so on.

Comment: You probably go the wrong direction, as your first priority should be analyzing the styles with proper tools, and then go back to source files, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Debugging_CSS or https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: I understand, I did understand and analyse the styles but I am not able to find a file where I could edit or tweak the code.

As in, to update and maintain the website one logs into the SQL Server and IIS, however once I navigate to the website directory I am met with a list of sub directories that I have difficulty working with. As mentioned they go by Modules, Logs, Bin, Admin, web.config, Default.aspx, Global.aspx and so on. I do not know where to look for, the file I need to edit so that the footer's position changes.